# Can't deploy app engine project (for jsp file)

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, environment-variables

When i deploy my eclipse appengine project their is no error and successfully deployed. But when i add a .jsp file in my war folder, i can't deploy. The error message is ==> **java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE.**
[image]

**my eclipse jre home definition is ==>**
[image]

**eclipse.ini** 
[image]

**pc environment variable**

[image]

**and  path**

[image]

Where is the problem??? I cant understand? Please help someone...

Answer (score 0):

In the eclipse.ini file the change is ==>

```
-vm 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
```

Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=(must be the java version.)